# SELECT remaining rows for each parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server database, of which I need to select the remaining rows from two views.

The thought behind it is this: I store game divisions in one table, and clans in another.

- The `vwGetGameDivisions` gets all the games that can be subjected to a division.
- The `vwGetClanDivisions` gets all the current game divisions the clan is subscribed to.

Currently, using

```
SELECT dbo.vwGetGameDivisions.name, dbo.vwGetClanDivisions.clanName
FROM   dbo.vwGetClanDivisions 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
       dbo.vwGetGameDivisions
    ON dbo.vwGetClanDivisions.gameName = dbo.vwGetGameDivisions.name
```

Gets all the 'divisions', and 'clans' registered to them.

I want to display the *remaining* divisions (the rest that a certain clan isn't registered to), so I can bind it to a `dropDownList` for a clan to see what they can still subscribe to.

I am still quite a newbee on SQL queries, and don't even know how to go about this..

I've tried `WHERE (dbo.vwGetClanDivisions.clanName = NULL)`, but that only returns divisions that have no clan at all.

EDIT - structures:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblSiteClanGameDivision](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [clanId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [gameId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [removed] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [dateAdded] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblSiteClanGameDivision] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblSiteGame](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [name] [nvarchar](200) NOT NULL,
    [description] [nvarchar](700) NULL,
    [thumbnailLocation] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [genreId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [isDivision] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK__tblGame__3213E83F03317E3D] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

---

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vwGetClanDivisions]
AS
SELECT dbo.tblSiteClanDetail.clanId, dbo.tblSiteClanDetail.clanName, dbo.tblSiteGame.id AS gameId, dbo.tblSiteGame.name AS gameName, 
                         dbo.tblSiteClanGameDivision.removed, dbo.tblSiteClanGameDivision.dateAdded
FROM   dbo.tblSiteClanDetail 
INNER JOIN  dbo.tblSiteClanGameDivision ON dbo.tblSiteClanDetail.id = dbo.tblSiteClanGameDivision.clanId 
INNER JOIN dbo.tblSiteGame ON dbo.tblSiteClanGameDivision.gameId = dbo.tblSiteGame.id

GO

CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vwGetGameDivisions]
AS
SELECT  id, name, thumbnailLocation, isDivision
FROM    dbo.tblSiteGame
WHERE   (isDivision = 1)

GO
```

Comment: You can use `select * from vw where id not in (YOUR CURRENT SELECT QUERY)`

Comment: table structure would help

Comment: My bad :) Added the structure now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is to use `INNER JOIN` to fetch the divisions the clan is signed up to, and `LEFT JOIN` to fetch the ones that they aren't.  `LEFT JOIN` will return divisions even if the clan isn't signed up to them, and then you filter out the ones where they are, like so:

```
-- Get matching divisions
SELECT gd.ID, gd.name, cd.clanName
FROM dbo.vwGetClanDivisions cd
INNER JOIN dbo.vwGetGameDivisions gd ON cd.gameId = gd.id

-- Get remaining divisions
SELECT gd.ID, gd.name, cd.clanName
FROM dbo.vwGetClanDivisions cd
LEFT JOIN dbo.vwGetGameDivisions gd ON cd.gameId = gd.id
WHERE gd.gameName IS NULL
```

Notice that the second query uses a `LEFT JOIN` to get all rows on both sides of the join, and the `WHERE` clause only shows rows where there is no matching game division for that clan.  You can also use table name aliases (as above) to shorten your queries.

**Edit:**
I should have been using a `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`, but in testing even that hasn't worked.  However the method given by @Vincent James of using `NOT IN` does (with the caveat that you have to specify which clan you are searching by, otherwise you will only get a list of empty divisions).  Here is a very basic SQL example:

```
CREATE TABLE #A (ID int, bID int)
CREATE TABLE #B (ID int)

INSERT INTO #B (ID) SELECT 1
INSERT INTO #B (ID) SELECT 2
INSERT INTO #B (ID) SELECT 3
INSERT INTO #B (ID) SELECT 4
INSERT INTO #B (ID) SELECT 5

INSERT INTO #A (ID, bID) SELECT 1,1
INSERT INTO #A (ID, bID) SELECT 1,2
INSERT INTO #A (ID, bID) SELECT 1,3
INSERT INTO #A (ID, bID) SELECT 2,1
INSERT INTO #A (ID, bID) SELECT 2,2
INSERT INTO #A (ID, bID) SELECT 3,3
INSERT INTO #A (ID, bID) SELECT 3,4

SELECT DISTINCT #B.ID 
FROM #B 
WHERE ID NOT IN(SELECT bID FROM #A WHERE ID = 1)

DROP TABLE #A
DROP TABLE #B
```

According to this, the entries for #A with an ID of 1 are linked to #B with an ID of 1, 2 or 3 (not 4 or 5).  Running the above query shows that the `NOT IN` method returns 4 and 5, which is correct.  I'm not entirely sure why the `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` isn't working, as the purpose of this is to return every row from #B regardless of if it was found in #A.

**Edit 2:**
Removed the Right Outer join method as I had two conflicting `WHERE` clauses that would prevent any rows being returned.  It isn't possible to do it using an outer join with the given table structure, because you need to select by the ID on the left, but only where the left side is null.  `NOT IN` is the correct method, as shown above.

**Edit 3**
Here is the stored procedure you should need to create.  This is better than hard coding the query as it protects you from [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetEmptyClanDivisions]
(
    @ClanID INT
)
AS
BEGIN
    -- Get the clan name
    DECLARE @ClanName nvarchar(255)
    SET @ClanName = SELECT TOP 1 clanName FROM tblSiteClanDetail WHERE clanId = @ClanID 

    -- Get a list of divisions the clan is registered for
    SELECT DISTINCT ID, name, @ClanName 
    FROM vwGetGameDivisions
    WHERE ID NOT IN(
        SELECT gameId 
        FROM tblSiteClanGameDivision 
        WHERE clanId = @ClanID
    )
END
```

Comment: I'm afraid `FROM dbo.vwGetClanDivisions cd` and `LEFT JOIN dbo.vwGetGameDivisions gd` makes no logicalities in my head.

Comment: The view dbo.vwGetGameDivisions is renamed as gd for shorthand reasons.  Likewise dbo.vwGetClanDivisions is renamed cd for the same reason.

Comment: Indeed.  Rather than having to repeat your long table multiple times, you can specify a shorter string after the table name in order to tell the query "I want to refer to this table as x from now on".

Comment: I understand that :P but then I'm reading it as `FROM dbo.vwGetClanDivisions dbo.vwGetClanDivisions` ?

Comment: You can also write it as "FROM dbo.vwGetClanDivisions AS cd" if you prefer.  "cd" defines the shorthand for the table, so without it cd.clanName wouldn't work, for instance.

Comment: I'm sorry for the long reply, SO isn't giving me updates from this :? I'll check now. - EDIT: It's giving me a blank result.

Comment: Edited answer to show an example of it working with the method suggested by @Vincent James - not sure why the join isn't working.

Comment: That `WHERE ID = 1` would need to be queried from my code (so I think). Over here it would be hard-coded. Am I wrong in saying that? If not, how can I do what I need? EDIT: Using it without the `WHERE` clause shows only the division which has no clan. Using the hard-coded clan name shows what i need.

Comment: Hard coding bad.  Stored procedure good.  See my latest edit.

Comment: @Maloric, I was using views, then adding `Sql Parameters` to populate the data. I was hoping to do this in a view, rather than a stored procedure :P Thanks for the update tho. PS: I havent directly referenced any tables. I've only used stored procedures and views.

Answer (score 2):

It is better to do the match with an ID field instead of a a name field.

```
SELECT dbo.vwGetGameDivisions.name
FROM dbo.vwGetGameDivisions
WHERE dbo.vwGetGameDivisions.name NOT IN (
    SELECT dbo.vwGetGameDivisions.name
    FROM   dbo.vwGetClanDivisions 
        INNER JOIN dbo.vwGetGameDivisions ON dbo.vwGetClanDivisions.gameName = dbo.vwGetGameDivisions.name

        )
```

Comment: Yes sry about that.  Typing it from my head

Comment: Even that, good sir, is something I am far from being able to do.

Comment: It is set logic.  Basically give me everything from set dbo.vwGetGameDivisions that is not included in subset, your select query.  IF that is blank the sets match meaning your query is returning the whole set.

Comment: Thanks for the update. This now only returns the one division that has no clan. I need the remaining divisions for all clans.

Comment: Ok let me look at all of the structure you just posted.  The error is elsewhere.